# Isolate scopes angularjs, ditching dependency injection, reusable components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolate-scope

I haven't really been fiddling for angularjs's directive for a while and I do not still have a good grasp on it. Before I dive into it, I am thinking react, on how they do their components.

So I have search on how to create reusable components using directives, and found this article:

http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2015/01/18/angular-directives-di/

But the implementation on his final solution is quite blurry, as I cannot figure out on how to use it correctly.

Let's say I create a title directive:

```
<epw-title store="epwEventStore">{{vm.title}}</epw-title>
```

And another directive that uses the same service `epwEventStore` so that it can update the state

```
<epw-event-list store="epwEventStore"></epw-event-list>
```

Where the `epw-event-list` renders a list and when clicked should change the value of `vm.title` of the `epw-title`.

How is this possible?

**Update**

**Q:** Are they nested?
**A:** No, they are siblings.

Comment: could you please add plunkr/fiddle

Comment: I could but I can't, because there aren't anything yet at the moment, and was hoping for someone to shed some light on the topic.

Comment: does this two directive element are nested

Comment: They are siblings. I'll add it to the question :D

Comment: how the value of `vm.title` is gonna change from `epw-event-list`?

Comment: That is the question, based on the article, it is possible, they are connected by the store they are subscribed to.

Comment: you could do that for that you need to add one more attribute in your directive element that would be look like `<epw-event-list store="epwEventStore" title="vm.title"></epw-event-list>` after that you should use `scope:{ 'store': '=', title: '=' }`

Comment: oh, I still don't have any idea on how does the service/store can change the value of the `vm.title`.

Comment: I don't get the "ditching DI" part of the title.

Comment: I get it after reading the blogpost. "Ditching DI" is a very wrong way of putting it imo. Not using it where it does not belong is not "ditching".

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't put Services inside Views

Just to avoid any misunderstanding, if `epwEventStore` is an *AngularJS Service* (such as `provider`, `factory`, `service`), it is not meant to be put as attribute value inside your template like that:

```
<epw-title store="epwEventStore">{{vm.title}}</epw-title>
```

In a well-designed decoupled architecture, your Views (template) should not "know" anything about your Services. They should only refer to `controllers`, `directives` and `filters`.

#### Different directives can use the same service

That means you can perfectly have

```
...
.directive("first", function(myService) { 
   ...
})

.directive("two", function(myService) { 
   ...
})
...
```

where, e.g., both directive can access and manipulate the same data.

#### Angular way is declarative

Following Angular's philosophy, if your `directive` depends on a Service, you declare it in the directive's definition. So whoever reads the code - knows immediately about all dependencies. This makes the code **readable**.

What the author of the article seems to be suggesting is to use `events` instead. Which is the publish-subscribe pattern. However, using it inside your `directive`, especially with `$rootScope`, makes the directive "leaky" as it is no more encapsulated and can both affect the external state and be affected. And worse - the reader has now manually search all your codebase for whoever is affected by the events emitted from the `directive`. This pattern has its uses but should be enjoyed with care.